# How can i fix ModelState.IsValid to work as attended?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hey not sure what going on here I did this before and it works just fine. But now my ModelState.IsValid is not working properly. In my model view, I have it set so if the textbox is left empty it will not execute the code inside the if statement but it returns true when there empty. Also, it seems like my field or not being set when I input them for some reason in the model CreaditCalculator.

```
Controller: CreditCardCalculatorController

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using reviewCreditCardPaymentCalculator.Models;

namespace reviewCreditCardPaymentCalculator.Controllers
{
    public class CreditCardCalculatorController : Controller
    {
        // GET: CreditCardCalculator
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(CreditCalculator credit)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                decimal financeCharge = 0.0m;
                decimal newBalance = 0.0m;
                decimal minPayment = 0.0m;

               
                if (credit.OldBalance <= 20)
                {
                    financeCharge = credit.OldBalance * 0.015m;

                    newBalance = credit.OldBalance * 1.015m + credit.Charge  - credit.Credit;

                    minPayment = newBalance;
                }
                else
                {
                    financeCharge = credit.OldBalance * 0.015m;
                    newBalance = credit.OldBalance * 1.015m + credit.Charge - credit.Credit;

                    minPayment = (newBalance - 20) * 1.10m;
                }

                ViewBag.Message = $"Finance Charge: {string.Format("{0:C}", financeCharge)}\r\n" +
                                    $"New Balance: {string.Format("{0:C}", newBalance)}\r\n" +
                                    $"Min Payment: { string.Format("{0:C}", minPayment)}";
            }

            return View();
        }


        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}

Model: CreditCalculator

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using reviewCreditCardPaymentCalculator.Controllers;

namespace reviewCreditCardPaymentCalculator.Models
{
    public class CreditCalculator
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your old balance")]
        public int OldBalance { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your new charge amount")]
        public int Charge { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your credit amount")]
        public int Credit { get; set; }
    }
}


View

@model reviewCreditCardPaymentCalculator.Models.CreditCalculator

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Credit Card Calculator";
}

<h2>Credit Card Payment Calculator</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary();

    <p><label>Old Balance: </label> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OldBalance)</p>

    <p><label>Charges: </label> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Charge)</p>

    <p><label>Credit: </label> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Credit)</p>

    <p><input type="submit" value="Calculate" /></p>

    @ViewBag.Message

}
```

Comment: Change your `int` to `int?` (aka `Nullable<Int32>`). Also you should use `<input type="number">` instead of `<input type="text">` for numeric form fields (you'll need to customize your `TextBoxFor` extension method).

Comment: Your form may be sending a GET not a POST (you can verify this by using the Network tool in your browser to monitor the submission request). Make the BeginForm output the correct HTML for the form tag, by stating it more like `@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "CreditCardCalculatorController", FormMethod.Post))`

Comment: thanks for the help sadly that not it something else is going on here not 100% sure yet. I will keep you post if i figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "CreditCardCalculatorController", FormMethod.Post))`

Comment: Did not work sadly. I did @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "CreditCardCalculator", FormMethod.Post)) it works but it gave me the same results as before.

Comment: Did you use the debugger to see what is happening step by step? I would use the debugger and see in autos tab. First of all, use debugger, it will tell you where are your model errors.

Comment: Woot found it! It was because I name in my public ActionResult Index(CreditCalculator credit) the same as my field Credit. i change it to cre and it work now. Thanks for the help! ps I try debugging before but was not even going in the model